# Fetch an image property on just the first row returned from the db in my linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm running this linq query to fetch data from my db, in my view I'm doing some lazy loading on the images, so I only want to fetch the first rows image. Leaving all the remaining rows image black/empty!

```
viewModel.Followers = yogaSpace.YogaSpaceFollowers
.Where(i => i.Status == FollowStatus.Following)
.OrderBy(i => i.DateUpdated).Select(i => new FollowResult
{
   Joined = i.DateUpdated,
   MemberId = i.YogaProfileId,
   Image = i.YogaProfile.PrimaryImage11, // fetch image only on the first row ?
   Name = i.YogaProfile.FirstName,
   EventsAttended = i.EventsAttended,
   IsATeacher = i.YogaProfile.IsATeacher
}).ToList();
```

Is it possible to fetch just the first rows image

> i.YogaProfile.PrimaryImage11

while leaving all remaining rows (2-N) empty without performing two different queries?
Can I do it in one query or two is what I want to know?

Comment: One way would be to turn it into a for loop, not use linq, and create tmp int to track and increment it each time you add an image

Comment: wouldn't that be really slow?

Comment: You could make two queries where one fills all the other fields, then the second would just fill the first ten images using .take(10)

Comment: right, but my question is asking if it can be done with one query, not two!

Comment: Without knowing how your models look like, maybe something like `Image = i.YogaProfileId == yogaSpace.YogaSpaceFollowers.Where(k => k.Status == FollowStatus.Following).OrderBy(k => k.DateUpdated).Select(k => k.YogaProfileId).First() ? i.YogaProfile.PrimaryImage11 : null` could work. According to the perfomance question, this could be a problem, though, where maybe an index on the _DateUpdated_ column could help

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really fit with the concept of SQL as having set-based operations - i.e. whatever you ask for is applied to the whole result set. So if you select a column, it will be selected in all the returned results. Consider storing the images outside the database, and just storing the path inside the database. Returning the path is from SQL cheap. Then the rest of your code can decide whether to actually display that image or not. Also you generally find that loading images from disk is faster than from a database.

Comment: Do you know how to store the images outside the db? I'm using Azure